# Is there an easy way to get out of this IF loop?

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I'm learning how to program and I feel that I'm always trapped with this kind of loops problems.
the question is, what would be the best way to get out of the if when the grouped bool is always true on Update (every frame). I need to execute the EUREKA only once.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GroupedWordsEyes : MonoBehaviour

{
    void Update()
    {
        //Check if words are grouped 
        bool grouped = CompareTags_Word1.colliding == true;

        if (grouped)
        {
            Debug.Log("EUREKAAAA!");
            //get out of the loop!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to get out of the loop? Just do nothing after your `Debug.Log`...

Comment: You're not in a loop -- chances are your `Update()` method is being called lots, and so that `Debug.Log` is being called lots

Comment: @canton7 - this is Unity3d. The `Update` function on a component is the game engine's update loop. This is effectively the body of a loop though no loop is written.

Comment: @McAden Sure, but `return` (as suggested by your answer) won't get you out of the game engine's main loop, either

Comment: Ok, it seems that idk what's technically called "a loop". As @canton7 said, the Update () is being called a lot of times, I just need to call it once, but idk how to do it.

Comment: @Matias what exactly is your goal? A bit unclear what you are trying to achieve with that .. you could simply disable the component after one successful if case like `enabled = false;`. This will stop Unity from executing `Update` anymore if that's what your looking for

Comment: I misunderstood the question, not realizing he was trying to not execute within the Update loop entirely. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want the code within the `if` to execute only when "colliding" changes.
Then you need to remember the previous value and check for changes:

**EDIT** changed code based on comments by OP

```
public class GroupedWordsEyes : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool previousGrouped = false; // assume that at first there is no collision

    void Update()
    {
        //Check if words are grouped 
        bool grouped = CompareTags_Word1.colliding == true;

        if (grouped != previousGrouped )
        {
            // always remember a change
            previousGrouped  = grouped;

            // only when just collided
            if (grouped)
            {
              Debug.Log("EUREKAAAA!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is giving me a Eureka at the very first frame, even if the bool grouped is false. When the CompareTags_Word1.colliding == true; then is giving me another Eureka, but if CompareTags_Word1.colliding == false; I'm receiving Eurekas as well :/

Comment: @Matias I altered the code a bit to only Eureka when there is a new collision

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want that `Update` is only called until the condition matches the first time.

You can simply disable that component by setting [`enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) to `false`.

This way `Update` is no longer called by Unity.

```
public class GroupedWordsEyes : MonoBehaviour   
{
    void Update()
    {
        //Check if words are grouped 
        if (CompareTags_Word1.colliding)
        {
            Debug.Log("EUREKAAAA!");
            
            enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm checking multiple objects colliding in real time. I need to keep the script running!

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Updating answer as I misunderstood the question.

You've got several options and it entirely depends on how you've architected.

1. One option is to deactivate (or even completely destory) the component. After you've done the one thing you need to do, call `this.enabled = false` - this will disable the component and no scripts will be run. This depends on architecture as this will also disable any other functions or child components attached to this one. You can mitigate this by ensuring this script only contains specific pieces that you want to be able to disable.
2. Create a flag that indicates whether the action has already been done.

   ```
   if (grouped && !hasDoneEureka)
   {
       // do the thing
       hasDoneEureka = true;
   }
   ```

Note that this will ensure you only run what you need to once, but probably isn't optimal since while it won't "do the thing" every time, it will CHECK every frame.

Comment: It doesn't work. It seems that return; won't help to get out of the game engine's main loop as someone said before.

Comment: great, I'm starting to understand. The problem now is that I can only execute this once, it seems that when hasDoneEureka = true; then I can keep getting into the if anymore. I need to run this and check the collision of multiple objects in real-time, so I can't just disable the script/object.

Comment: @Matias - in that case just remove the `return`... Next time it comes about it will bypass the if statement and, by extension, the "eureka" you refer to and keep going.

Comment: Mhhhh, same behavior if I remove the `return`. I can't trigger the `//do the thing` for a second time after setting the bool `true` inside the if.

Comment: @Matias isn't that the entire point of your question? you only want to do the Eureka thing once...